# Not able to call session destroy via api in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using rails 4.1.8. I have created an API in which user is able to create genrate the auth_token by sessions#create of devise, but now when i try to access sessions#destroy its response is "error: Please sign in or sign up before continuing".

sessions controller

```
def destroy
 user = User.find_by(authentication_token: request.headers['Authorization'])
 user.generate_authentication_token!
 user.save
 head 204 
end
```

When I post via postman to http://localhost:3000/api/users/sign_out, its giving above defined error.

routes

```
 GET    /api/users/sign_out(.:format)   api/devise/sessions#destroy
 GET    /api/users/sign_in(.:format)    api/sessions#new
 POST   /api/users/sign_in  api/sessions#create 
 DELETE /api/users/sign_out api/sessions#destroy
```

I want to call destroy so that it can generate new token. How to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to call it in sessions controller, finally i wrote this destroy method in users controller and called it from there. If any one knows the answer please post it, as this is a temporary solution only.